# Hypothesis testing, good data and bad data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, noise

This might be more a question of methodology, but I'm wondering if there exist statistical solutions to alleviate the issue.

**CONTEXT**
We're gathering data for a customer acquisition funnel for our website, it has two major steps:

1. **acquisition**: sending people to our website
2. **conversion**: are these people signing up on our website

For acquisition, we provide people with a URL that they click on to visit our site. However, we know that roughly 20-30% of targeted people do not click on the URL, but instead enter our host-name directly in Google or their browser address bar. When people do that, we have no means of knowing which campaign / effort brought them to our website.

**THE DEBATE**
My colleague and I disagree, we have two very different views on the issue:

- **My view**: since we cannot track these users reliably (*we can only assume, to an extent*) we should treat those direct users as lost data for the acquisition funnel (*this is part of data acquisition, sometimes data is bad and you shouldn't use it*).
- **His view**: we should track those people in *some* manner, such as time-boxing the period when they are on our website.

I then argue that we *could* do that, but that the resulting data would be very error-prone. Visitors could be coming from parallel campaigns (*data pollution*). In addition, that changes the way our *previous* tests were measured, causing an unfair positive bias on the new data sets.

- is one of us outright wrong?
- if I'm wrong, how could I account for that super risky-data so that I can know exactly how it affects our reliable data?

Comment: What is the actual question you and your colleague are trying to answer?

Comment: I guess the question would be: should we try to measure the unreliable data or simply discard it as unusable data?

Comment: I think @Alexis means "actual question" as what, precisely, is the original research question this data is for?

Comment: We're doing A/B tests on different discussion scripts to see which ones perform better (which has the highest ratio of people being exposed to the script and visiting our website).